# How to use $and operator in mongodb - java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

How do we query for mongo using logical AND($and),

Example :
collection : Subject

From collection subject I need to get all the records satisfying the condition,

totalmarks!=10 and totalmarks!=15.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Equivalent in java driver.

```
List<DBObject> criteria = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
criteria.add(new BasicDBObject("totalmarks", new BasicDBObject("$ne", 10)));
criteria.add(new BasicDBObject("totalmarks", new BasicDBObject("$ne", 15)));
DBCursor dbCursor = collection.find(new BasicDBObject("$and", criteria));
```

Comment: Driver version 3.2 DB, DBCollection and DBCursor classes are deprecated. See above from @arnavakhoury.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, for newer versions, you can use Bson object as a filter.

```
mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("DBName");
MongoCollection<Document> col = mongoDatabase.getCollection("CollectionName");
Bson filter = Filters.and(
              Filters.ne("totalmarks", 5),
              Filters.ne("totalmarks",15));
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = col.find(filter).iterator();
```