# MongodDB with Java driver: How to find nested atributes and how to use "and" operator

Tags: java, mongodb

The collection:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a7e"},"name":"Harry Potter","species":"human","gender":"male","house":"Gryffindor","dateOfBirth":"31-07-1980","yearOfBirth":{"$numberInt":"1980"},"ancestry":"half-blood","eyeColour":"green","hairColour":"black","wand":{"wood":"holly","core":"phoenix feather","length":{"$numberInt":"11"}},"patronus":"stag","hogwartsStudent":true,"hogwartsStaff":false,"actor":"Daniel Radcliffe","alive":true,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/harry.jpg"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a7f"},"name":"Hermione Granger","species":"human","gender":"female","house":"Gryffindor","dateOfBirth":"19-09-1979","yearOfBirth":{"$numberInt":"1979"},"ancestry":"muggleborn","eyeColour":"brown","hairColour":"brown","wand":{"wood":"vine","core":"dragon heartstring","length":""},"patronus":"otter","hogwartsStudent":true,"hogwartsStaff":false,"actor":"Emma Watson","alive":true,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/hermione.jpeg"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a80"},"name":"Ron Weasley","species":"human","gender":"male","house":"Gryffindor","dateOfBirth":"01-03-1980","yearOfBirth":{"$numberInt":"1980"},"ancestry":"pure-blood","eyeColour":"blue","hairColour":"red","wand":{"wood":"willow","core":"unicorn tail-hair","length":{"$numberInt":"14"}},"patronus":"Jack Russell terrier","hogwartsStudent":true,"hogwartsStaff":false,"actor":"Rupert Grint","alive":true,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/ron.jpg"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a81"},"name":"Draco Malfoy","species":"human","gender":"male","house":"Slytherin","dateOfBirth":"05-06-1980","yearOfBirth":{"$numberInt":"1980"},"ancestry":"pure-blood","eyeColour":"grey","hairColour":"blonde","wand":{"wood":"hawthorn","core":"unicorn tail-hair","length":{"$numberInt":"10"}},"patronus":"","hogwartsStudent":true,"hogwartsStaff":false,"actor":"Tom Felton","alive":true,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/draco.jpg"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a82"},"name":"Minerva McGonagall","species":"human","gender":"female","house":"Gryffindor","dateOfBirth":"04-10-1925","yearOfBirth":{"$numberInt":"1925"},"ancestry":"","eyeColour":"","hairColour":"black","wand":{"wood":"","core":"","length":""},"patronus":"tabby cat","hogwartsStudent":false,"hogwartsStaff":true,"actor":"Dame Maggie Smith","alive":true,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/mcgonagall.jpg"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a83"},"name":"Cedric Diggory","species":"human","gender":"male","house":"Hufflepuff","dateOfBirth":"","yearOfBirth":{"$numberInt":"1977"},"ancestry":"","eyeColour":"grey","hairColour":"brown","wand":{"wood":"ash","core":"unicorn hair","length":{"$numberDouble":"12.25"}},"patronus":"","hogwartsStudent":true,"hogwartsStaff":false,"actor":"Robert Pattinson","alive":false,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/cedric.png"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a84"},"name":"Cho Chang","species":"human","gender":"female","house":"Ravenclaw","dateOfBirth":"","yearOfBirth":"","ancestry":"","eyeColour":"brown","hairColour":"black","wand":{"wood":"","core":"","length":""},"patronus":"swan","hogwartsStudent":true,"hogwartsStaff":false,"actor":"Katie Leung","alive":true,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/cho.jpg"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a85"},"name":"Severus Snape","species":"human","gender":"male","house":"Slytherin","dateOfBirth":"09-01-1960","yearOfBirth":{"$numberInt":"1960"},"ancestry":"half-blood","eyeColour":"black","hairColour":"black","wand":{"wood":"","core":"","length":""},"patronus":"doe","hogwartsStudent":false,"hogwartsStaff":true,"actor":"Alan Rickman","alive":false,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/snape.jpg"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a86"},"name":"Rubeus Hagrid","species":"half-giant","gender":"male","house":"Gryffindor","dateOfBirth":"06-12-1928","yearOfBirth":{"$numberInt":"1928"},"ancestry":"half-blood","eyeColour":"black","hairColour":"black","wand":{"wood":"oak","core":"","length":{"$numberInt":"16"}},"patronus":"","hogwartsStudent":false,"hogwartsStaff":true,"actor":"Robbie Coltrane","alive":true,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/hagrid.png"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a87"},"name":"Neville Longbottom","species":"human","gender":"male","house":"Gryffindor","dateOfBirth":"30-07-1980","yearOfBirth":{"$numberInt":"1980"},"ancestry":"pure-blood","eyeColour":"","hairColour":"blonde","wand":{"wood":"cherry","core":"unicorn tail-hair","length":{"$numberInt":"13"}},"patronus":"","hogwartsStudent":true,"hogwartsStaff":false,"actor":"Matthew Lewis","alive":true,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/neville.jpg"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a88"},"name":"Luna Lovegood","species":"human","gender":"female","house":"Ravenclaw","dateOfBirth":"13-02-1981","yearOfBirth":{"$numberInt":"1981"},"ancestry":"","eyeColour":"grey","hairColour":"blonde","wand":{"wood":"","core":"","length":""},"patronus":"hare","hogwartsStudent":true,"hogwartsStaff":false,"actor":"Evanna Lynch","alive":true,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/luna.jpg"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a89"},"name":"Ginny Weasley","species":"human","gender":"female","house":"Gryffindor","dateOfBirth":"11-08-1981","yearOfBirth":{"$numberInt":"1981"},"ancestry":"pure-blood","eyeColour":"brown","hairColour":"red","wand":{"wood":"yew","core":"","length":""},"patronus":"horse","hogwartsStudent":true,"hogwartsStaff":false,"actor":"Bonnie Wright","alive":true,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/ginny.jpg"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a8a"},"name":"Sirius Black","species":"human","gender":"male","house":"Gryffindor","dateOfBirth":"03-11-1959","yearOfBirth":{"$numberInt":"1959"},"ancestry":"pure-blood","eyeColour":"grey","hairColour":"black","wand":{"wood":"","core":"","length":""},"patronus":"hare","hogwartsStudent":false,"hogwartsStaff":false,"actor":"Gary Oldman","alive":false,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/sirius.JPG"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a8b"},"name":"Remus Lupin","species":"werewolf","gender":"male","house":"Gryffindor","dateOfBirth":"10-03-1960","yearOfBirth":{"$numberInt":"1960"},"ancestry":"half-blood","eyeColour":"green","hairColour":"brown","wand":{"wood":"cypress","core":"unicorn tail-hair","length":{"$numberDouble":"10.25"}},"patronus":"wolf","hogwartsStudent":false,"hogwartsStaff":true,"actor":"David Thewlis","alive":false,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/lupin.jpg"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a8c"},"name":"Arthur Weasley","species":"human","gender":"male","house":"Gryffindor","dateOfBirth":"06-02-1950","yearOfBirth":{"$numberInt":"1950"},"ancestry":"pure-blood","eyeColour":"blue","hairColour":"red","wand":{"wood":"","core":"","length":""},"patronus":"weasel","hogwartsStudent":false,"hogwartsStaff":false,"actor":"Mark Williams","alive":true,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/arthur.jpg"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a8d"},"name":"Bellatrix Lestrange","species":"human","gender":"female","house":"Slytherin","dateOfBirth":"","yearOfBirth":{"$numberInt":"1951"},"ancestry":"pure-blood","eyeColour":"brown","hairColour":"black","wand":{"wood":"walnut","core":"dragon heartstring","length":{"$numberDouble":"12.75"}},"patronus":"","hogwartsStudent":false,"hogwartsStaff":false,"actor":"Helena Bonham Carter","alive":false,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/bellatrix.jpg"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a8e"},"name":"Lord Voldemort","species":"human","gender":"male","house":"Slytherin","dateOfBirth":"31-12-1926","yearOfBirth":{"$numberInt":"1926"},"ancestry":"half-blood","eyeColour":"red","hairColour":"bald","wand":{"wood":"yew","core":"phoenix feather","length":{"$numberDouble":"13.5"}},"patronus":"","hogwartsStudent":false,"hogwartsStaff":false,"actor":"Ralph Fiennes","alive":false,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/voldemort.jpg"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a8f"},"name":"Horace Slughorn","species":"human","gender":"male","house":"Slytherin","dateOfBirth":"","yearOfBirth":"","ancestry":"pure-blood","eyeColour":"green","hairColour":"blonde","wand":{"wood":"cedar","core":"dragon heartstring","length":{"$numberDouble":"10.25"}},"patronus":"","hogwartsStudent":false,"hogwartsStaff":true,"actor":"Jim Broadbent","alive":true,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/slughorn.JPG"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a90"},"name":"Kingsley Shacklebolt","species":"human","gender":"male","house":"","dateOfBirth":"","yearOfBirth":"","ancestry":"pure-blood","eyeColour":"brown","hairColour":"brown","wand":{"wood":"","core":"","length":""},"patronus":"lynx","hogwartsStudent":false,"hogwartsStaff":false,"actor":"George Harris","alive":true,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/kingsley.jpg"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a91"},"name":"Dolores Umbridge","species":"human","gender":"female","house":"Slytherin","dateOfBirth":"","yearOfBirth":"","ancestry":"half-blood","eyeColour":"brown","hairColour":"grey","wand":{"wood":"birch","core":"dragon heartstring","length":{"$numberInt":"8"}},"patronus":"persian cat","hogwartsStudent":false,"hogwartsStaff":true,"actor":"Imelda Staunton","alive":true,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/umbridge.jpg"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a92"},"name":"Lucius Malfoy","species":"human","gender":"male","house":"Slytherin","dateOfBirth":"","yearOfBirth":{"$numberInt":"1954"},"ancestry":"pure-blood","eyeColour":"grey","hairColour":"blonde","wand":{"wood":"elm","core":"dragon heartstring","length":{"$numberInt":"18"}},"patronus":"","hogwartsStudent":false,"hogwartsStaff":false,"actor":"Jason Isaacs","alive":true,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/lucius.jpg"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a93"},"name":"Vincent Crabbe","species":"human","gender":"male","house":"Slytherin","dateOfBirth":"","yearOfBirth":"","ancestry":"pure-blood","eyeColour":"black","hairColour":"black","wand":{"wood":"","core":"","length":""},"patronus":"","hogwartsStudent":true,"hogwartsStaff":false,"actor":"Jamie Waylett","alive":false,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/crabbe.jpg"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a94"},"name":"Gregory Goyle","species":"human","gender":"male","house":"Slytherin","dateOfBirth":"","yearOfBirth":"","ancestry":"pure-blood","eyeColour":"","hairColour":"brown","wand":{"wood":"","core":"","length":""},"patronus":"","hogwartsStudent":true,"hogwartsStaff":false,"actor":"Josh Herdman","alive":true,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/goyle.jpg"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a95"},"name":"Mrs Norris","species":"cat","gender":"female","house":"","dateOfBirth":"","yearOfBirth":"","ancestry":"","eyeColour":"yellow","hairColour":"brown","wand":{"wood":"","core":"","length":""},"patronus":"","hogwartsStudent":false,"hogwartsStaff":true,"actor":"Maxime, Alanis and Tommy the cats","alive":true,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/norris.JPG"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5c7d656a82bb44be9e770a96"},"name":"Argus Filch","species":"human","gender":"male","house":"","dateOfBirth":"","yearOfBirth":"","ancestry":"squib","eyeColour":"","hairColour":"grey","wand":{"wood":"","core":"","length":""},"patronus":"","hogwartsStudent":false,"hogwartsStaff":true,"actor":"David Bradley","alive":true,"image":"http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/filch.jpg"}
```

My attemps:

1. Show all characters that are alive ("alive" property equal to true) and also students ("hogwartsStudent" property equal to true).

   ```
   FindIterable<Document> aliveStudents = harrypotter.find(and(eq("alive", "true"), eq("hogwartsStudent", "true")));
   System.out.println("---------- ALIVE STUDENTS ----------");
   for (Object character : aliveStudents) {System.out.println(((Document) character).toJson());}
   ```
2. Show all characters whose "wood" attribute of the "wand" property is "holly"

   ```
   FindIterable<Document> wand= harrypotter.find(eq("wand", "holly"));
   System.out.println("---------- CHARACTERS WITH HOLLY WAND ----------");
   for (Object character: wand) {System.out.println(((Document) character).toJson());}
   ```

I only need the correct harrypotter.find sentence for both cases. Other ways to do this like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121848/how-to-use-and-operator-in-mongodb-java-driver) dont work for me because my teacher asked for doing this with this manner. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not sufficiently clear about what was the result of your approaches. Do they give execution errors or don't they bring the results you expected?

For the first problem, it seems that **alive** and **hogwartsStudents** are of boolean type, so I recommend to use **true** instead of **"true"**

```
FindIterable<Document> aliveStudents = harrypotter.find(and(eq("alive", true), eq("hogwartsStudent", true)));
System.out.println("---------- ALIVE STUDENTS ----------");
for (Object character : aliveStudents) {System.out.println(((Document) character).toJson());}
```

For the second problem, I think you should use the **fieldName.fieldProperty** syntax:

```
FindIterable<Document> wand= harrypotter.find(eq("wand.wood", "holly"));
System.out.println("---------- CHARACTERS WITH HOLLY WAND ----------");
for (Object character: wand) {System.out.println(((Document) character).toJson());}
```